# What is the Dell "FGA module"

Tags: dell-xps

When looking at the list of items included with the Dell XPS 15 I see:
**FGA Module:**
Catalog Number / Description = PPAN1303_023/PPAN1305_027/BTO
Product Code = FG0011

What does it represent?

I found one guess that FGA stands for "Fast Genetic Algorithm" used for facial recognition, but didn't get any results at Dell when searching for it.

Comment: I couldn't find any results *anywhere* explaining what that is. Pretty impressive.

Comment: Maybe it's an Easter egg.

Comment: Right now I am getting hits on google. Sadly they all go to superuser.com/questions/446445/what-is-the-dell-fga-module  :)

Comment: Thats a *small* problem with SU. We're highly ranked. Most other hits seem to be of specifications lists.

Comment: Maybe it's a Field Programmable Gate Array (FPGA) which are used by hardware accelerators.

Comment: This was even asked on Dell forums, no answer: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19427728/20014325.aspx#20014325

Comment: Yes, that was the guess of "Fast Genetic Algorithm".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a friend working with Dell and this is the response that I got:

> FGA module is not customer or system related. It is just an internal code to identify fixed hardware configurations and gets downloaded to the invoice/summary by default

Comment: Yes "Fast Track system" means "fixed hardware configurations". They don't offer any options, they are pre-built and ready to ship.

Answer (score 4):

I contacted Dell and this was the response:

*The FGA module is an internal SKU that designates whether the system is a Fast Track system or build to order.*